# Making a total of points from a table in Google spreadsheets;unique values have to appear only once

Tags: google-sheets, unique, spreadsheet

I made this table (the names a,b,c,...of the contestants are dynamic so they change sometimes).

[image: see example 1]

Now I want to make a total of the 4 different contests, but the contestants may appear only once and there has to be made a total for each contestant (see desired result)

[image: see desired result]

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=INDEX(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(E3:H);;9^9))))
```

then you can do simple:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({A3:A, 1*TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(E3:H),,9^9)))}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col1)''", ))
```

Comment: Neat - I guess you then need to do some grouping?